# Book suggestions (Stochastics, Brownian Motion etc.)

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, brownian-motion, book-recommendation

This is my first post where I'm not requesting help with a problem. Nevertheless, I'm writing here for some book suggestions. After recently finishing my maths degree and as a result of my Random Processes Module, I've developed a keen interest in all things Markov, the lecture notes in this module were poor and feel like I'd like to do some further reading and strengthen ideas that I should have concretely already learnt. It would be great if anyone on here could recommend books oriented around the following; Markov Chains, Queues, Modelling, Invariant Distributions, Brownian Motion etc. Feel free to delve into my previous posts; some give a brief view of what stuff I was learning. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Peres Yuval - Brownian motion

Comment: Some recommendations of stochastic calculus can be found at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1188316/good-introductory-book-for-stochastic-calculus-it%C5%8D-calculus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest the following books:

0. J. M. Steele, Stochastic Calculus and Financial Applications (*)
1. R. van Handel, Stochastic Calculus, Filtering, and Stochastic Control (*)
2. J. R. Norris, Markov Chains
3. Peter Mörters and Yuval Peres, Brownian Motion
4. Sheldon Ross, Simulation
5. Barry L. Nelson, Stochastic Modeling: Analysis and Simulation
6. Oksendal, Stochastic Differential Equations

(*) personal favorites :)

There are also some general books that cover several topics in your list. for example, you can look at Grimmett and Stirzaker: Probability and Random Processes.

Comment: Brilliant thank you so much :)